# Animate transition on a react component that i hide on re-render

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

i m using reactjs and i have a datepicker component that i hide when the user clicks outside of the component element.

the code snippet is like so:

```
`
class DatePicker extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
      state= { focus: false }  // when focus: false i hide the dates component 
  }    
  .......
  render(){
    const { focus } = this.state

    return(
      <input type="text" placeholder="start date">
      <input type="text" placeholder="start date">
      {focus &&  <DatesContainer ...props>} // if focus==false i dont show the <DatesContainer> component.I need to hide it with fade out or something.
    )
  }
}`
```

So when the user clicks outside of the `<DatesContainer/>` the state.focus updates to false, the  re-renders and, this time, the `<DatesContainer/>` is not render at all, so far so good. But i need to hide it with a 0.3s animation.

Any opinions on that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd update the state to have a `transitioning` property. Using CSS animations or transitions, and some conditional rendering, we can apply a new class to the DatesContainer, detect when an animation is finished and change the focus state to false.

You'll have to set transitioning to true in the state whenever you click outside it.

It may look something like this:

## CSS

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.fading {
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    will-change: opacity;
}
```

## JS

```
//import your styles here

class DatePicker extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
      state= { focus: false, transitioning: false }
  }    

  handleFade() {
    this.setState({transitioning: false})
  }

  render(){
    const { focus, transitioning } = this.state

    return(
      <input type="text" placeholder="start date">
      <input type="text" placeholder="start date">
      {focus &&  <DatesContainer 
                   className={transitioning === true ? "fading" : null} 
                   onAnimationEnd={transitioning === true ? () => this.handleFade() : null}
                 /> 
      }
    )
  }
}`
```

Comment: But ,inside render(), if focus is false, the && <DatesContainer /> will not render at all. It will just vanish.

Comment: @TheoItzaris Yes that's true, but you had a function to deal with changing focus to true correct? It will render there, then when focus is lost, it should set transitioning to true, which would give the fade effect. In `handleFade` you can also set `focus` back to false.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between my answer and previous is you're able to set specific actions to certain animation keyframes.

The key point is to provide animation name as a function parameter

### CSS

```
.Modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.ModalOpen {
    animation: openModal 0.4s ease-out forwards;
}
.ModalClosed {
    animation: closeModal 0.4s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes openModal {
    0% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
    100% { transform: translateY(0);   }
}

@keyframes closeModal {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-100%);}
}
```

### JS

```
const modal = ({ 
  isShown, isMounted, 
  initiateUnmountAction, unmountAction
}) => {
  const cssClasses = [
    "Modal",
    props.isShown ? "ModalOpen" : "ModalClosed"
  ];
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isMounted && <div className={cssClasses.join(' ')}
        onAnimationEnd={event => 
          {event.animationName == "closeModal" && unmountAction}
      }>
        <h1>A Modal</h1>
        <button className="Button" onClick={initiateUnmountAction}>
          Dismiss
      </button>
      </div>}
    </Fragment>

  );
};
```