# Why my state doesn't update even in callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I call a function to change my states with onClick, one state which is in a parent component (I change it with a function I pass in props) and another state which is in my component.
The first works fine,
But the second doesnt update, even if I test it and call the result in callback.

I put some console log in the function before the setState and in call back, and it logged but doesn t change the state which stays the same

```
class CaseProducts extends Component {
  state = {
    position_selector: 0,
    case_sales: "-100%",
    case_products: "0%",
  };

  changeSelector = () => {
    console.log(this.props);
    if (!this.props.products_on) {
      console.log("product: off");
      this.setState(
        { position_selector: -106, case_sales: 0, case_products: "-100%" },
        () => console.log(this.state.position_selector),
      );
    } else {
      console.log("product_on");
      this.setState(
        { position_selector: 0, case_sales: "-100%", case_products: "0%" },
        () => console.log(this.state.position_selector),
      );
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="button-category">
        <div
          className="blue-button"
          style={{ right: this.state.position_selector }}
        >
          <text className="position-selector-products">Produits</text>
          <text className="position-selector-sales">Ventes</text>
        </div>
        <button
          className="change-button-sales"
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.updateDatas();
            this.changeSelector();
          }}
        >
          Ventes
        </button>
        <button
          className="change-button-products"
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.updateDatas();
            this.changeSelector();
          }}
        >
          Produits
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = { products_on: true };

  updateDatas = () => {
    console.log("bonjourrrrr");
    this.setState({ products_on: !this.state.products_on });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route
          exact
          path={ROUTES.HOME}
          component={props => (
            <CaseProducts
              {...props}
              products_on={this.state.products_on}
              updateDatas={this.updateDatas}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The setState of product_on works fine it's the setState of change_selector, case_sales and product_sales which doesn t update at all.

Does anybody have an idea what it could be?

Comment: I added your code to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/bGbwQoY?editors=0010) and it works as expected. Can you verify that the pen works as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be happening is the fact that you're creating a new internal state depending on a passed property. Is like you don't know which one "will end first".

If you want to update the internal state depending on a passed property, you should be using `getDerivedStateFromProps` method instead (in previous versions of React, could be `componentWillReceiveProps` method)

```js
class CaseProducts extends React.Component {
  state = {
    position_selector: 0,
    case_sales: '-100%',
    case_products: '0%'
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.products_on) {
      return ({
        position_selector: -106,
        case_sales: 0,
        case_products: '-100%'
      });
    } else {
      return ({
        position_selector: 0,
        case_sales: '-100%',
        case_products: '0%'
      });
    }
  }

  render() {

    return ( <
      div className = 'button-category' >
      <
      div className = 'blue-button'
      style = {
        {
          right: this.state.position_selector
        }
      } >
      <
      text className = 'position-selector-products' > Produits < /text> <
      text className = 'position-selector-sales' > Ventes < /text> <
      /div> <
      button className = 'change-button-sales'
      onClick = {
        () => {
          this.props.updateDatas()
        }
      } >
      Ventes <
      /button> <
      button className = 'change-button-products'
      onClick = {
        () => {
          this.props.updateDatas()
        }
      } >
      Produits <
      /button> <
      /div>  
    )
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    products_on: true
  }

  updateDatas = () => {
    console.log('bonjourrrrr');
    this.setState({
      products_on: !this.state.products_on
    })
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      CaseProducts products_on = {
        this.state.products_on
      }
      updateDatas = {
        this.updateDatas
      }
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<div id="app" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but i have an animation (transition: .5s) on my scss which doesn't work anymore, Do someone knows why?

Comment: I think is because component is rerendering and not actually changing any css property which triggers the transition. 
You can check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492111/animate-transition-on-a-react-component-that-i-hide-on-re-render 
or this 
https://web-design-weekly.com/2015/02/05/applying-react-js-css-transitions-initial-render/ (which leads to https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html)

Comment: If the answer helped to solve your problem, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you calling `this.props.updateDatas();` this method is causing state change in the parent, this will result a re-render for the parent which contain child `CaseProducts` causing a re-render and a `state` reset . this is why `CaseProducts` state not changing!

Try removing `this.props.updateDatas()` and check for state change in `CaseProducts` component.

Comment: It works but I need to use this.changeSelector() too just after the this.props.upadateDatas(), how do i do?

Comment: @Constantin the best way is to use global state management like redux which you can hold all you app states in one place called store and retrieve needed state. Or you can a add new property let's call it button_number  in you parent and change it depending on the button clicked from child then pass it as props to your child to check on each render if any button is clicked or not.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this.setState in function changeSelector in child component wrong you must change like follow.

```
changeSelector = () => {
        console.log(this.props);
        if (!this.props.products_on) {
            console.log('product: off');
            this.setState({ position_selector: -106, case_sales: 0, case_products: '-100%' }); 
            console.log(this.state.position_selector);
        } else {
            console.log('product_on');
            this.setState({ position_selector: 0, case_sales: '-100%', case_products: '0%' });
            console.log(this.state.position_selector));
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are wrong he's using  `setState ` callback to check if the state updated!

Comment: Yes I am using setState callback to check if it update but it doesnt update :((((

Comment: I think `setState` syntax is wrong. It will structure like `this.setState({field: 'new value'})`. Not `this.setState(
        { position_selector: -106, case_sales: 0, case_products: "-100%" },
        () => console.log(this.state.position_selector),
      )`. This function `() => console.log(this.state.position_selector)` is not allowed in `setState` function.

Comment: @TrầnCông No you're wrong, it a call back function which is allowed in setstate